# Class not creating new instance of JTextField

Tags: java, swing

My aim here is to be able to create multiple JTextFields, using my ClockBuilder class. I wonder if you could give some advice on how I might achieve this goal. I've included an SSCCE of my code.

My full program creates an array of 145 cities from a txt file. I use this array to fill a jlist, then +/- buttons should allow the user to add/remove cities from being displayed. I'm at the stage where I have the JList and buttons functioning correctly. It adds/removes cities into a separate array list. I've been trying to use this array list to create multiple instances of my JTextField but, I am not able to achieve this, where am I going wrong?

I've simplified this in my SSCCE where I am manually creating two Clockbuilder classes, why is it that New York displays correctly but London doesn't display at all? I'm quite new to programming and am still getting my head around classes, methods and constructors, please excuse me if I have phrased parts of my question incorrectly I hope I have been clear in what I wish to achieve.

**ClockBuilder.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class ClockBuilder extends JTextField{
    ClockView view;

    public ClockBuilder(){
      super(8);
    }

    public JTextField ClockBuilder(String city){
      Border lineBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK,1);
      Font font = new Font("Bradley Hand ITC", Font.BOLD, 24);
      setFont(font);
      setEditable(false);
      setFocusable(false);
      setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(lineBorder, city));
      return this;
   }
}
```

**View.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class ClockView{
    JFrame clockFrame;
    JPanel displayArea;
    JPanel clockPanel;

    String cities[] = {"London","New York","Barcelona", "Toronto"};

    public ClockView() {
        clockFrame = new JFrame("World Clock");
        clockFrame.setSize(400,400);
        clockFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        clockFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container contentPane = clockFrame.getContentPane();
        clockPanel = new JPanel();
        clockPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

        ClockBuilder clock = new ClockBuilder();
        clockPanel.add(clock.ClockBuilder("London"));
        ClockBuilder clock2 = new CLockBuilder();
        clockPanel.add(clock2.ClockBuilder("New York"));

        contentPane.add(clockPanel);
        clockFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, your ClockView class should most definitely not extend the ClockBuilder class. Doing this is misusing inheritance since the one class does not pass the "is-a" test, with potential for breaking your code.

Comment: Ok, thankyou I'm still trying to wrap my head around using extend if I'm honest. I tried looking up the "is-a" test you mention but failed to find anything about it could you please expand on what you mean by this?

Comment: Some links:  [link 1](http://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/inheritance-composition-relationship.php), [link 2](http://www.coderanch.com/t/412328/java/java/Relationship), [link 3](http://www.artima.com/objectsandjava/webuscript/CompoInherit1.html), [link 4](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076814/core-java/inheritance-versus-composition--which-one-should-you-choose-.html).

Comment: Also, ClockBuilder should not extend JTextField since you ***never*** use it as a JTextField. No you are using it but with a strange pseudo constructor??? You may wish to read some basic Java textbooks before trying to tackle GUI stuff.

Comment: What is is not genuine about the constructor? Ideally I should do that my basic level of java/programming logic is quite low I suppose but this project is due soon and I'm trying to get it done.

Comment: I don't understand that but hopefully I will sometime soon. Cruel to be kind, is what comes to mind here for me. Thanks for your help though I'll come back to stack overflow when I'm, afloat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my comments, you're mis-using inheritance in that the ClockView class should not extend ClockBuilder. ClockView will hold ClockBuilder instances and thus there is a "has-a" relationship here, not an "is-a" relationship. Also and again, your ClockBuilder class has a "pseudo-constructor", a method with the same name as the class, including capitalization, but which is not truly a constructor since it returns something. Get rid of it. Either use an appropriate method with an appropriate method name or a true constructor.

Also, you're using JTextFields in a very non-JTextField way, where you seem to display the text but not let the user edit it. In this situation, better to use JLabels placed into a GridLayout-using JPanel. Better still, if all you want to do is display a list of clock times, then I would use a JList, one with a custom renderer that displays the appropriate time of the clock with a surrounding title border.

Comment: I understand the relationships now after reading the links you shared with me. I'm not quite there on understanding what you mean with the constructor but I'll research it further to try a get a better understanding. 

I also understand that I am using JTextFields in a strange way, it's simply how my lecturer did it in an example he gave us in class. I'll try using a JLabel or JList instead.

Answer (score 3):

> why is it that New York displays correctly but London doesn't display at all?

By default a JFrame uses a `BorderLayout`. Also by default when you add a component to the frame it will be added to the "CENTER" of the BorderLayout. However, only one component can be displayed in the center, so only the last component added (New York) is displayed.

I don't really understand what you are attempting to do so I can't suggest a complete solution, but the basic solution is to use a different layout manager to manage the components. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information.

As a simple example to get you started add the following to see the difference:

```
clockFrame = new JFrame("World Clock");
clockFrame.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
```

Comment: I tried implementing your solution but it did not fix my problem. Am I not adding my component to a JPanel though? Where the default layout manager is FLowLayout? and then adding that panel to my JFrame? Thankyou for your help.

I suppose what I am attempting to do is create lots of these JText fields with a for loop, looping through an array of cities.

Comment: @Nai: you haven't posted a real sscce. 1+ to this answer. And why a bunch of JTextFields? Why not a JTable?

Comment: Really? I tried to follow this [post](http://www.sscce.org/). Yes using a table did cross my mind but this was how it was assigned to me by my lecturer.

Comment: @Nai: per your link: `"It is important to ensure that the code given to others can be 'copied, pasted, compiled, run' so that they can help quickly and with a minimum of fuss."` -- meaning there must be a main method, somewhere. Also you never show an attempt to create JTextFields in a for loop.

Comment: I can run this code? I'm sorry I didn't realise that meant including a main method. Well I figured I would simplify it as much as I could. If someone could help me understand why the code I included wasn't working as I wanted I presumed I could expand I what they told me to include a for loop on my own.